# String compare without using standard library function

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

I am new to C programming. This is just a beginners question. I am trying to implement string compare without using standard function.Here i have used dynamic memory allocation and used `fgets()`. But the second string is not inputted. Can anyone help me point out the problem? The code is given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_strcmp(char*, char*);

int main()
{
    int a, n;
    printf("enter the length of strings\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    getchar();

    char *s1 = (char *)malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    printf("enter the string1\n");
    fgets(s1, n, stdin);
    getchar();

    char *s2 = (char *)malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    printf("enter the string2\n");
    fgets(s2, n , stdin);

    if (s1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc error!!");
    }

    if (s2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc error!!");
    }

    a = my_strcmp( s1, s2);

    if (a == 0)
    {
        printf("the strings are equal");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("the strings are not equal");
    }
    free (s1);
    free (s2);
    return 0;
}

int my_strcmp( char *s1, char*s2)
{
    while (*s1)
    {
        if (*s1 == *s2)
        {
            s1++;
            s2++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    if ( *s1 == *s2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (*s1 > *s2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor comments on your code. `sizeof(char)` is going to be `1`, so don't make things needlessly complex. I'm not sure why you have `getchar` after `fgets`. Particularly since you don't for the last one. You should `exit` with a non-zero return value during `malloc` failures to stop the program. You are missing `\n` at the end final outputs. Others have explained the **off-by-one** error with your strings. It is one of several common mistakes in C programming with strings.

Comment: What you call the "length of strings" and how code uses `n` is a problem.  Say the longest "string" is "abc".  This needs a buffer 3+1+1 long.  (3 for `"abc"`, 1 for `'\n'` and 1 for `'\0'`).  Do `char *s1 = malloc(n + 2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `n` parameter of `fgets` is the size of the buffer *including null-terminator*. Thus, it reads up to at most `n - 1` characters, and fills the last spot with a null-terminator. Your second call to `getchar` (after the first `fgets`) then reads that last character, *not* the newline, so the second call to `fgets` stops early because it immediately hits a newline.

Instead, you'll want to allocate `n + 1` characters for each string, and call `fgets` with `n + 1` as well.

Also, you should check for `malloc` failure *before* trying to write to `s1` or `s2`.

Comment: Good catch on the using memory **before** checking for failure (`malloc`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.can u please explain it little detail if u dont mind :)

Comment: "first call to getchar then reads that last character, not the newline" likely _does_ read a newline.  The _first_ `getchar();` is after the `scanf()` and certainly consumes the `'\n'` when OP enters the length value.  The _second_ `getchar()` is the problem.  Its presence between the 2 `fgets()` should be eliminated.

Comment: OP should allocate `n + 2` for each string as OP likely views the length of the strings entered to not include the `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux by using `fgets` with `n + 1`, you won't get the newlines, though. That's what the `getchar` calls are for (I presume).

Comment: @DrewMcGowen .I have allocated n +1 memory location and called fgets with n +1 as well.But when i input a larger string (>n).I still get the same error even if i am using getchar().Can u please point out the   problem in thatv case.

Comment: @vipil that's because you'll only read the first `n` characters, and `getchar` will read whatever character's next (which in that case, is *not* a newline)

Answer (score 0):

The code can be changed like this.

```
getchar(); //Fix
fgets(s1, n, stdin);
getchar();
char *s2 = (char *)malloc(n * sizeof(char));
```

Set `n=n+1` after getting from user. This is to deal `'\0'` character